# jQuery UI Tabs Caching v1.10.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

- jQuery: v 1.9.1
- jQuery UI: v 1.10.3
- Browser: Internet Explorer 10.0.920

I'm using jQuery UI Tabs to display groups of data. Each tab's content is retrieved using AJAX. The tab content cannot be cached. Prior to v 1.10 we used the Tabs cache property along with the ajaxOptions cache property to control caching. Everything was cool.

With the upgrade to 1.10 these two params have been removed. The functionality can be had by using the beforeLoad event. So this is the new tabs code...

```
$(function () {
    $("#tripYears").tabs({ 
        active: 0,
        beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.ajaxSettings.cache = false;
        } 
    });
});
```

This appears to work in every browser except IE. I've tested with IE versions 8 and 10. Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari don't cache the tab data at all. Was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: That's strange ajaxSettings.cache = false must work on IE; have you checked the request in the net panel? Do you see the timestamp added to the requested page?

Comment: @Edward. Here are the headers from Fiddler...  
  
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Tue, 28 May 2013 01:09:15 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2
    Expires: Tue, 28 May 2013 04:09:15 GMT
    Cache-Control: public, max-age=10800
    Last-Modified: Thu, 23 May 2013 03:10:02 GMT
    Set-Cookie: swTripsYear=2011; expires=Thu, 27-Jun-2013 01:09:15 GMT
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    Content-Length: 68478
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Type: text/html  

Doesn't look like the correct Expires header is being sent?

Comment: ui.ajaxSettings.cache is undefined, the above code doesn't in neither IE nor Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

With default Ajax tab loading, every time you switch back to a tab it reloads the Ajax. The "cache" parameter was there to prevent that, but it's been deprecated now but as jQueryUI point out you can roll your own with beforeLoad.

You seem to be trying to get the browser to cache the Ajax itself. However the tab's contents are already there in the DOM, so really you don't need to make an Ajax request at all, when you return to a previously loaded tab.

You just want to stop jQuery re-loading that tab's content. So something like this will prevent that:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
   beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.panel).html()) {    // If content already there...
            event.preventDefault();      // ...don't load it again.
        }
    }
});
```

That's entirely inside jQueryUi/ jQuery so isn't dependent on any browser Ajaxy stuff.